# Updating Header in Excel with vba, doesn't overwrite existing values

Tags: excel, vba, header

I have this vba script that writes some information in the header of an excel file. Sadly it doesn't update what's already written in the right and left header, althogh I set the headers to empty before writing to them again.
(see code and pictures below)

Has anyone an idea what's wrong? 
Thanks in advance!

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader = ""
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = ""
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightHeader = ""


ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader = Zeichnung '.Value
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = Bezeichnung '.Value
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightHeader = index_kpl '.Value
```

EDIT:
also, it seems that the last two caracters of the older string are removed. It removes two additional caracters if I remove the last two in advance.

EDIT2:
IF I run the script step by step it works.

If I enable / disable ScreenUpdate it has no effect.

EDIT3
waiting (Application.wait()) between clearing and writing to the header doesn't help either.

EDIT4
The entire code is as follows (requested by george86):

```
Sub ausdrucken()

Sheets("alle_Zuweisungen").Select

Bezeichnung = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Steuerung").Range("J3").Value
Bezeichnung = CStr(Bezeichnung & "")
Zeichnung = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Steuerung").Range("J4").Value
Zeichnung = CStr(Zeichnung) ' & "")
aktueller_Index = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Steuerung").Range("J5").Value
index_kpl = "Änderungsindex " & aktueller_Index
index_kpl = CStr(index_kpl & "")
benutze_Zeilen = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
PrintArea = "A4" & ":" & "J" & benutze_Zeilen


ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = PrintArea '"PrintArea:PrintArea"
'Application.PrintCommunication = False


ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader = ""
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = ""
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightHeader = ""

Application.Wait (2)

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader = ""
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = ""
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightHeader = ""

'Application.Wait (1)
'newHour = Hour(Now())
'newMinute = Minute(Now())
'newSecond = Second(Now()) + 2
'waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
'Application.Wait waitTime


ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader = Zeichnung 'CStr("&L" & Zeichnung) '.Value
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = Bezeichnung ' CStr("&C" & Bezeichnung) '.Value
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightHeader = index_kpl 'CStr("&R" & index_kpl) '.Value

Debug.Print (Zeichnung)
Debug.Print (Bezeichnung)
Debug.Print (index_kpl)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

[image: first]

[image: second]

[image: third]

Comment: from where you are trying to enter the details. Is it from a cell in excel sheet

Comment: What happens if you debug.print `Zeichnung, Bezeichnung` and `index_kpl` at that point?

Comment: @george86, Yes, I use the content of different cells to define those variables.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, If I debug.print it shows all of the variables correct, without the old one.

Comment: This algorithm is corect. What if you run it step by step and check the result of each step with print preview? You should see the current headers disappearing then reappearing.

Comment: @AcsErno If I run the script step by step, and check the preview it runs as it should (At least not this Problem). It first deletes the contents and writes the new content.

Comment: @Marco Just be curious what happens if you put a time delay in your code ... 
      newHour = Hour(Now())
      newMinute = Minute(Now())
      newSecond = Second(Now()) + 1
      waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
      Application.Wait waitTime

Comment: @george86 I added an "Application.Wait (1)". It still doesn't work. Does you code the same?

Comment: @george86 I tried with your code as well, but it still doesn't work. But thanks for the input!

Comment: @what version of Excel are u using ? Do you mind showing the code as it is. May be i can try it on mine and see what is happening.

Comment: @george86 I'm using Excel 2010.

Comment: @george86 I just found a solution. I added the whole code anyways. maybee it helps someone.

Comment: @Marco  nice to know that u found a solution..

Answer (score 3):

Many Thanks for the suggestions!

I found a solution.
From the macro I recorded earlier there was the line
     Application.PrintCommunication = False

...within the code.
Upon removal it worked as you would expect.